# choose correct statement ?10

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

consider the three subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ namely 
$$
\begin{split}
A_1 &= \left\{(x,y)\left| x^2 +y^2 \le 1 \right. \right\}\\
A_2 &= \left\{(1,y) | y \in \mathbb{R}\right\}\\
A_3 &= \{(0,2)\}
\end{split}
$$
then there always exist a continuous real valued function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$f(x) = a_j \quad \forall x \in A_j, \quad j =1,2,3$$

1. if and only if at least two of the two of the member $a_1,a_2$ and $a_3$ are equal
2. if $a_1=a_2=a_3$
3. for all real values of $a_1,a_2,a_3$
4. if and only if $a_1=a_2$

**My attempts:**

by Brouwer fixed-point theorem. $a_1$ will not map to $a_2$ and $a_3$, so option 1 is  correct that is if and only if at least two of the member $a_1,a_2$ and $a_3$ are equal,  so that $a_2$ will map to $a_3$ so that we can write as $a_2=a_3$.

is my answer is correct or not? Please tell me the solution

Comment: We do not map a1, a2 or a3 to anything.  We are mapping A1 to a1, A2 to a2, and A3 to a3.  Please review your reasoning.  There is one special relationship between two of A1, A2, and A3.  What is it?  Why does it matter?

Comment: thanks @ ross millikan,,,let me thinks again